# Send Email asynchronous in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I want to send email on a action & I want to deliver it later.
I am using deliver_later  method of ActionMailer but when the control reaches to this line

```
CustomerMailer.create_order_confirmation_mail(deal, deal.product.title, @user).deliver_later
```

It first sends the mail & render the view.
How to send this mail later after rendering the view?

Comment: `.deliver_later(queue: "test_queue")` or `.deliver_later(wait: 1.hour)` this way you can try

Answer (score 1):

Using `delayed_job` gem and it will just look like:

```
CustomerMailer.delay.create_order_confirmation_mail(deal, deal.product.title, @user)
```

[Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)